# Prove formula's tautology

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Prove that a formula that only consists of variables, logical negation and logical equality, and in which all variables and negation appear for an even number of times, must be tautological.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the truth table of negation and biconditional (what you have called logical equality)
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
  p & q & \neg p & p \leftrightarrow q \\
  \hline
  1&1&0&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  0&0&1&1
 \end{array}$$

We can define
\begin{align}
p \leftrightarrow q \quad &:= \quad p+q+1 \text{(mod 2)}\\
\neg p \quad &:= \quad p+1 \text{(mod 2)}
\end{align}

Now we can translate any formula of propositional logic which contains only the connectives negation and biconditional, into an algebraic expression. Note that since we are working in mod 2, $p+p=2p=0$ (because 2=0).

Now it should be straightforward to prove the statement in the question.